# Embed Github contributions graph in website

Tags: html, github, github-api

Is there a way to embed the Github contributions graph in HTML5?

[image]

Comment: If you do this with the GRID CSS layout *BEWARE* there is a **1000 row or column limit in Chrome**. Ref: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1009

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I wrote a JavaScript library to do that: [**github-calendar**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-calendar).

[Here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-calendar#installation) is an example how to use it:

```
<!-- Prepare a container for your calendar. -->
<script
  src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/IonicaBizau/github-calendar/gh-pages/dist/github-calendar.min.js"
>
</script>

<!-- Optionally, include the theme (if you don't want to struggle to write the CSS) -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/IonicaBizau/github-calendar/gh-pages/dist/github-calendar.css"
/>

<!-- Prepare a container for your calendar. -->
<div class="calendar">
    <!-- Loading stuff -->
    Loading the data just for you.
</div>

<script>
    new GitHubCalendar(".calendar", "your-username");
</script>
```

[Here](http://ionicabizau.github.io/github-calendar/example/) you can see it in action:

[image]

Basically, since we need cross domain requests we need a proxy. It makes a request to GitHub profile page (`github.com/<user>`) and then brings back the needed stuff from there.

For more information, check out the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-calendar#installation).

Comment: @geek4079 Don't forget to accept the answer then. :)

Comment: @geek4079 You can do that by clicking the `✔` button (left side of the answer).

Comment: @geek4079 Is there a specific reason why you accepted the other answer and not mine? That looks more like a comment.

Comment: I was sure I had, sorry :)

Comment: I'm trying to use it, but never get a response

Comment: @geek4079 If you notice any bugs, please report them as issues on GitHub. It's easier to track.

Comment: @Ionică Bizău any chance that you can add a simple guide to how someone using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to build a github page would implement this?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't work with Jekyll but just a little bit. The idea is that you have to do three things: have a container in the HTML, load the js and CSS of this library, and initialize the calendar. Maybe open an issue in the repository and will get some help from the community.

Comment: @IonicăBizău. No worries, I implemented a minimal version of your script myself. Let me know if you're interested in knowing how.

Comment: Maybe you can open a pull request or issue in the repository and provide this info. I'm sure it will help others as well!

Comment: as of today(2018-08-24), the js seems to be broken with an error "github-calendar.min.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at github-calendar.min.js:1"

Comment: @IonicăBizău thanks, the js from` cdn.rawgit.com/` seems not updated yet, so I changed to `https://ionicabizau.github.io/github-calendar/dist/github-calendar.min.js` and it's working properly now.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'm looking for a reactjs component for the same. I tried but failed to do so. Can you please help me. I even installed it `npm install --save github-calendar`, but then what to do after that. How to import or call this component.

Comment: @Tanzeel I suggest asking a question about that. I hope the React experts will help you.

Comment: @IonicăBizău. For now I used `GitHubCalendar from 'react-github-calendar'` and it is working for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @IonicăBizău unable to get current streak, logest steak and contribution number. I used all parameters but not working

Answer (score 16):

This guy: http://www.rshah.org/ wrote a Github chart API. This could definitely help: http://ghchart.rshah.org/ . Plus it is only HTML, so couldn't get any cleaner. 
Just change the username and alt tag to yours.

Comment: https://github.com/2016rshah/githubchart-api  -- the code is not "just html" requires his service to be running, so it raises a lot of reliability and privacy questions

Comment: I meant the code you have to embed is HTML, you don't have to take care of any JS code.

Comment: @Soren it's opensource so you can easily host it yourself on Heroku as it's ruby based

Answer (score 8):

You can scrape the HTML at this url: `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions` and put it on your page.

Comment: Even tho I upvoted, I'm not sure about the Fair Use policy about scraping pages of GitHub's servers.

Comment: I *needed* to know and for future readers: [User-to-server requests are limited to 5,000 requests per hour and per authenticated user.](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: The API this answer is referring to is not available any more.

[Grass Graph](https://grass-graph.moshimo.works/) is what I found as the best option to do what you're looking for.

You can get the graph generated as simple image by simply putting it so:

```html
<img src="https://grass-graph.moshimo.works/images/mkartak.png">
```

Comment: Link is not working

Comment: Looks like they've taken the website down - unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this with Angular 4 by doing the following:

1. Make a HTTP GET request to the url mentioned by @jianweichuah `https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions`.
2. You'll need a proxy to get past the CORS issue just as the github-calendar library does. `proxy-url/https://github.com/users/<username>/contributions`
3. Then present it back in the template.

Sadly you don't get all the information easily, but it is in the SVG details.

I have a write-up of my exact steps here: https://www.chiangs.ninja/blog/
And an example of it on the main site under the GitHub tab. I also grabbed my user information from the GitHub API and populated it around the chart.

Comment: Your blog link is broken

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021 December:

```
<img src="https://ghchart.rshah.org/username" alt="2016rshah's Github chart" />
```

Answer (score 1):

###### There is an almost exact copy of the original GitHub Contribution Graph I wrote.

https://github.com/lengthylyova/gh-contrib-graph

---

###### To get this:

[image]

###### Do this:

```html
<!-- GOES INTO HEAD -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lengthylyova.pythonanywhere.com/static/gh-contrib-graph/gh.css">

<!-- GOES INTO BODY -->
<div id="gh" data-login="YOUR GITHUB LOGIN"></div>

<!-- GOES INTO THE END OF BODY -->
<script src="http://lengthylyova.pythonanywhere.com/static/gh-contrib-graph/gh.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with code:

You will need to generate a personal access token with the scope `public_repo`.
https://github.com/settings/tokens

HTML:

```html
<table id="contribution-table">
  <!-- The table will be generated here -->
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const username = "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE"; // Replace with your Github username
const accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"; // Replace with your personal access token
const apiUrl = "https://api.github.com/graphql";

const query = `
  query {
    user(login: "${username}") {
      contributionsCollection {
        contributionCalendar {
          totalContributions
          weeks {
            contributionDays {
              contributionCount
              date
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const contributions = data.data.user.contributionsCollection.contributionCalendar;
    const weeks = contributions.weeks;

    // Create the table structure based on contributions data
    const contributionTable = document.getElementById("contribution-table");
    for (let dayOfWeek = 0; dayOfWeek < 7; dayOfWeek++) {
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      for (let weekIndex = 0; weekIndex < 53; weekIndex++) {
        const week = weeks[weekIndex];
        const contributionDay = week.contributionDays[dayOfWeek];
        const contributionCount = contributionDay ? contributionDay.contributionCount : 0;
        const td = document.createElement("td");
        let contributionColor;
        if (contributionCount < 5) {
          contributionColor = 0;
        } else if (contributionCount < 10) {
          contributionColor = 1;
        } else if (contributionCount < 15) {
          contributionColor = 2;
        } else if (contributionCount < 20) {
          contributionColor = 3;
        } else {
          contributionColor = 4;
        }
        td.className = `color-${contributionColor}`;
        row.appendChild(td);
      }
      contributionTable.appendChild(row);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching GitHub contributions:", error);
  });
```

CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.color-0 { background-color: #fff; }
.color-1 { background-color: #9be9a8; }
.color-2 { background-color: #40c463; }
.color-3 { background-color: #30a14e; }
.color-4 { background-color: #216e39; }
```