# How to embed GitHub projects and timeline into website

Tags: javascript, python, html, github, github-api

I am creating a developer portfolio website from scratch. In my projects section I want to have a collection of all of my GitHub projects, and a timeline that can be used to filter down projects by the date they were last worked on. However, Research is proving difficult, with all results being about GitHub pages, which is a totally separate thing. What I want to know is how would I go about embedding this stuff into my website. Is this even possible or would I have to manually add projects and somehow code a timeline with JavaScript. I think it's worth mentioning that I am using Python and Flask to build my website, so maybe I can do some web scraping or use python to make the timeline, or even interact with the API somehow?

Comment: I would recommend simply using the Github API to fetch a list of your repositories.  Given that data you can order it and display it however you want, either in Javascript on the frontend or in Python on the backend.  See https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repositories-for-a-user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Github contributions graph in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516592/embed-github-contributions-graph-in-website)

Comment: @MichaelHelvey should I make it so that the API is called every time the page is loaded, so that the projects are always up to date, or should I call the API every week for example and store results in a database?